# Can not understand how to get the value from setters and getters class

Tags: android, eclipse, baseadapter, getter

I am parsing json data and displaying in custom ListView using BaseAdapter. I have **no problem in parsing** the data. Also don't have any problem setting the data to ModelClass.java (setters and getters class) only question is **how to get the data from ModelClass.java**. Please help.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // url to make request(to get the latest 20 feeds).
    private static String url = "http;.....";
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_BODY = "body";
    private static final String TAG_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_DATE_TIME = "date_time";
    private static final String TAG_DEPARTEMENT = "department";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_INCLUDE = "include";
    private static final String TAG_MEDI_TYPE = "mediaType";
    private static final String TAG_PRIORITY = "priority";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at";
    private static final String TAG_USER_ID = "user_id";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ListView listViewFeeds;
    // String mTitle, mBody;
    List<ModelClass> model = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* To display the feed */
        listViewFeeds = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFeeds);
        listViewFeeds.setAdapter(new NewAdapter(this));

        Feeds feeds = new Feeds();
        feeds.execute();
    }

    public class Feeds extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading ...");
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                String jsonData = stringBuilder.toString();

                // Displaying json data in logcat.
                Log.d("Latest 20 feeds", jsonData);

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonData);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String mTitle = object.getString("title");
                    String mBody = object.getString("body");
                    System.out.println("Titlte: " + mTitle);
                    System.out.println("Body: " + mBody);
                    // Setting the data to ModelClass
                    ModelClass mc = new ModelClass(mTitle, mBody);
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}

class NewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ModelClass> list;
    Context context;

    NewAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
        // return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_feed_view, parent,
                false);
        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleFeeds);
        TextView body = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewBody);

        ModelClass temp = list.get(position);
        title.setText(temp.title);
        body.setText(temp.body);
        return row;
    }

}
```

This is my ModelClass.java

```
public class ModelClass {
    String title;
    String body;

     ModelClass(String title, String body) {
     this.title = title;
     this.body = body;
     }
}
```

activity_main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewFeeds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

single_row_feed_view.xml file(row appears in ListView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitleFeeds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewColor"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitleFeeds"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit hard to work out the exact question because you are asking how to get the value from setters and getters class but your ModelClass has no getters or setters.

You can put getters into your ModelClass, but you may not technically need them if its in the same package.

You should look at this tutorial. It helped me a lot. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
   //Inside your Model class:

 public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
    }

    public String setTitle(String givenTitle){
    this.title = givenTitle;
    }

    public String getBody(){
    return this.body;
    }

    public String setTitle(String givenBody){
    this.body = givenBody;
    }
```

Comment: thankyou, but this is not my question. How to display in list?

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do, you will need not just a complete Model class (yours isn't at this moment) but also an Adapter class. And I know that it is not my bussiness, but I think you should read about it before getting your hands dirty. You can start here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ this is a nice tutorial, and it helped me to achieve what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you need to put getters and setters in your model class. In terms of putting the values in a list and formatting the list item, then you need a custom list adapter.  Then create a list of the items you want to put in the list adapter.. then show the list.  Below is an example.

```
enter code here
 public class ExampleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ExampleModel> {

 private Context                     context;
 private ArrayList<ExampleModel> items;

 public ExampleListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleModel> items) {
    super(context, R.id.result_list_item_direction_icon, items);

    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    View rowView = convertView;

    //Get rowView from inflater
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.id.yourcustom_layout, parent, false);

    // Get reference ids from the rowView
   //example
    TextView item = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemID);


    // Set the values for items in custom list view

    item.setText(items.get(position).yourGetter());


    return rowView;
 }
```

}

then in the in the class you want to use it…

```
enter code here
  ArrayList<t> yourList = new ArrayList<t>();
  yourList = getValuesFromDBOROtherSource;//make sure the return value is list!
  yourCustomAdapter = new ExampleListAdapter(getActivity(), yourList);

  setListAdapter(yourCustomAdapter);
```